# Highcharts: send chart object as Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want a Javascript function that will build different Highcharts when I send the charts as a variable. This is because my users can draw and redraw charts with triggers. My question is similar to this one except I want to pass all the chart parameters to the function and I want to call the function onload and when certain buttons are clicked. 
[How to create highcharts dynamically on click buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448911/how-to-create-highcharts-dynamically-on-click-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more reading, I think this will work:

```
<script>
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }]
};

function draw() {
    new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    draw();
});
```

Comment: Hi @red5, Has your problem been solved? Feel free to ask about Highcharts in case of doubt.

Comment: @ppotaczek: yes, thank you. I guess it was a silly question, but I'm still learning Highcharts.